# Extract only date part in a datetimein LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

We have some data in a `DataTable` and we are using the query like this to get what we need.

```
IEnumerable<Results> subResult = from query in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                             select new Results
                                  {
                                      Name = query.Field<string>("Name"),
                                      Date = query.Field<DateTime?>("Date")
                                  }
```

This above query returns what i need but date in full format (Ex:  `m/dd/yyyy hh:min:sec am/pm`) but we need only date part of it(only mm/dd/yyyy need to be pulled in). When looked in the properties of this, couldn't find an implicit way to get it, please help me in getting this result. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK there is no Date Class in .net, if you want pure date you should write a Class for that, otherwise you can pull out the part as a string.

Comment: You are talking about the string representation. But you don't show how you create that. Please show the code where you convert the date to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime class has all the properties you just mentioned. You should try to fix your display with the ToString("anyformatyouwant") formats.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Date = query.Field<DateTime?>("Date").Date
```

Comment: It gives me error saying system.date does not contain definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first arguement of type <system.DateTime> could be found. (are you mssing using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @svs "are you mssing using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: Does the column in source datatable nullable?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you just the date part:

```
IEnumerable<Results> sub-result= from query in datatable.AsEnumerable()
    where new Results
    {
        Name = query.Field<string>("Name"),
        Date = query.Field<DateTime?>("Date").Date
    }
```

However if you just want to *display* the date somewhere (meaning you're not using this to do date grouping, etc. then I would just specify the display format in your UI layer.

Comment: It is worth noting that Date simply zeroes the time element, but the time element is still there when doing comparison / equality operations.

Comment: It gives me error saying system.date does not contain definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first arguement of type <system.DateTime> could be found. (are you mssing using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no Date Class in .net, if you want pure date you should write a Class for that, otherwise you can pull out the part as a string

```
DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

gives you the current date in string type, but if you get the `.Date` part it gives you a `DateTime` object which still has a time part showing `AM 12:00:00:0 blah blah`